# AngularJS Controller does not fire when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I enter the Reports page the controller fires and executes some code in my `services.js` file.  The service return information from the database and that information it is used to show/Hide  tags in the HTML.  However, if I refresh the Search page, my controller does not fire and the Reports page shows all the  tags, the functionality to hide some of the  tags does not work

My code is as follows.

**route.js**

The name of the controller is: `reportsCtrl`

```
 application.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
 function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $routeProvider
    .when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
    })
    .when('/search', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/search.html',
        controller: 'searchCtrl'
    })
    // REPORTS SERVER REPORTS.
    .when('/reports', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports.html',
        controller: 'reportsCtrl'
    })
    // REPORTS (DASHBOARD REPORTS).
    .when('/dashboard/report', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/unloads.html',
        controller: 'reportunloadsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/unloads', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/unloads.html',
        controller: 'reportunloadsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/carriers', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/metrics.html',
        controller: 'reportcarriersCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/vendors', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/metrics.html',
        controller: 'reportvendorsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/items', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/metrics.html',
        controller: 'reportitemsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/exceptions', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/metrics.html',
        controller: 'reportexceptionsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/loadtypes', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/loadtypes.html',
        controller: 'reportloadtypesCtrl'
    })
    .when('/dashboard/report/pallettypes', {
        templateUrl: window._ctxpath + '/resources/partials/reports/metrics.html',
        controller: 'reportpallettypesCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/dashboard'
    });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}])
```

here is the actual controller, it is in file reportsReportServer.js

```
var reportsCtrl = application.controller('reportsCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$context', '$reportVisibilitySvc',
function($rootScope, $scope, $ctx, $reportVisibilitySvc) {

    var testField = null;
    testField = "I am in the reports (form report server) controller";
    console.log(testField);

    $rootScope.getReportPermissions = function() {
        if( $ctx.dock ) {
            $ctx.rpt = null;
            let month = null;
            let endDate = $ctx.range.split(' - ')[1];
            let date = new Date(endDate);
            month = date.getMonth() + 1;
            $ctx.rpt = $reportVisibilitySvc.Values(month, $ctx.dock);
        }
    };
    $rootScope.getReportPermissions();
}]);
```

Here is the code for the service... it is in a file called services.js

```
//This service is used to return the information for the database and see what report in the Reports page should be hidden.
var $reportVisibilitySvc = application.service('$reportVisibilitySvc', [ 'baseService', '$rootScope', '$resource',
function(baseService, $rootScope, $resource) {

    var $rpt = $resource(window._ctxpath+'/rpt/:p1/:p2',
            { p1 : '@p1', p2 : '@p2' },
            {savem : {method : 'POST', isArray : true}
    });

    this.Values = function(month, dock) {
        if (dock !== null) {
            console.log('I am in the service.js file, in the $reportVisibilitySvc service, in the this.Values function')
            return $rpt.save({p1 : 'values', p2 : month}, dock, function(o, head) {});
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Again.  The controller and the service executes when I enter the reports page, but I also want it to fire if I refresh the page by clicking the refresh button on Google Chrome, any ideas please?

Comment: What errors are thrown? Is server configured for html5Mode?

Comment: Hola como estas?  No errors at all, I just doesn't fire. and the code to hide/show the HTML tags doesn't work at all.  But if I go to the home page and then come back to the Reports page, all works fine the .js code executes and the sections in the HTML are hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:  I noticed that after refreshing the page the contextCtrl controller fired, so what I did was to put the code found in the reportsCtrl in the contextCtr controller to call the $reportVisibilitySvc service again.

```
if ( sessionStorage.getItem('LV_CTX_DOCK') && $ctx.range ) {
    $ctx.rpt = null;
    $ctx.dock = null;
    let month = null;
    let endDate = $ctx.range.split(' - ')[1];
    let date = new Date(endDate);
    month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    // get the dock
    $ctx.dock = sessionStorage.getItem('LV_CTX_DOCK');
    // get the data from the database to see what reports are hidden/visible
    $ctx.rpt = $reportVisibilitySvc.Values(month, $ctx.dock);
}
```

this worked as what I needed.